# Map().set() does not add element in Collection, using NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I recently have had a problem when coding using NativeScript.
I tried using Map() object as a Collection, but its set() method seems not to work.

I use the following snippet :

```
var r = new Map();
r.set("one", "two");
console.dir(r);
```

It however outputs an empty Map(), and I do not know why...

For your convenience, here is a link to a NativeScript PlayGround: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=evhIxX&v=2

I inserted the snippet inside home.components.ts

Thanks alot!

LMy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it works, if you try `r.get("one")` then you will see `two` in console.

May be `console.dir` does not handle `Map` as expected. You may report that in the GitHub project.